# Ubuntu, cannot access local webserver from local IP

Tags: networking, ubuntu, webserver

First I developed simple local webserver that serves at IP:192.168.1.105. Here is an image of the webserver accessed from self browser
[image: localwebserver].

In another PC that connected in same local network I'm able to ping the webserver IP. Here is an image showing ping, but I cannot access the webserver via browser [image: ping].

I checked firewall, it's inactive already, what is probably the cause the trouble?

Comment: Is one on Ethernet and the other on Wifi?

Comment: both at same wifi, i just confused while able to pinging but cannot access its webserver

Comment: What's the actual message? You do have pretty poor reception on the server. It might simply be running into a timeout?

Comment: no any mesage popped out, just browser message shown that unable to connect, but i able to ping to the webserver, techincally if it is in the same local network, it must be able to access isnt? i dont know if there is additional setup, but previously i had developed webserver with these setting and it is works, but now it is just fail, just wondering what probably cause the trouble

Comment: Your wifi hotspot probably blocks traffic on port 8000.

Comment: i already checked that my firewall inactive already, also tried with different ssid network and IP, but still get same result

Comment: You deployed it but probably didn't develop it. Did you check your webserver logs? The message behind your ping window actually is different depending on what might be issue. As it is the server might not be responding or the logs might tell your it's running into an issue.

Comment: just copied the exact same program on different computer, however somehow i was able to control from another, but my computer as webserver still unable to be controlled from another IP in same local network.